# unzip or extract a file inside of dropbox using the php api

Tags: php, dropbox-api, dropbox-php

I'm working on a project with a friend and we would like to find a way to upload a .zip or .rar or .tar file to Dropbox, and then when the file is inside of Dropbox extract the files of that file.  Everything must be done using the API.

Why we want to do this?  Our project is a website builder and we already implement the Dropbox uploading of every single file and folders but we would like to speedup the process, creating a zip/rar/tar file, upload it to Dropbox and then extract the files to make it faster.

Is this possible?

Comment: I'm doubtful you will be able to do this from within Dropbox, you're going to have to browse their API documentation, on the surface it sounds like a job more suited for version control (git/svn). https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs

Comment: You could have your users upload a .zip then have your server unzip it and upload the individual files to Dropbox.  Maybe not the best solution, but it would at least allow your users to upload compressed files.

Answer (score 0):

No, Dropbox doesn't currently offer a way to remotely unzip uploaded zip, etc. files like this, so this isn't currently possible.

Answer (score 0):

Dropbox provides automation to unzip files. To activate it you need to open Dropbox folder's menu, when outside that folder. Then select 'Add automation' and then select 'Unzip files'.

Any file uploaded to that folder will be unzipped automatically.